# Python 3 Replace Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little trouble with Python. Here is code:

```
f = open('/path/to/file', 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()
postgres = filedata.replace('# DBENGINE=MYSQL', 'DBENGINE=PGSQL')
dbname = filedata.replace('# DBNAME=DB1', 'DBNAME=DB1')
dbrwuser = filedata.replace('# DBRWUSER="user1"', 'DBRWUSER="user1"')
f = open('/path/to/file', 'w')
f.write(postgres)
f.write(dbname)
f.write(dbrwuser)
f.close()
```

As you can see I'm trying to read a big file and when I try to replace it it just replaces "Postgres" and it does not make change "dbname, dbrwuser" etc. So I tried to figured it out but couldn't do it.

Any idea or sample?

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid `f.read()` for large files. It reads the whole file into memory. `with open(filename) as f: for line in f: ...` is generally better since it reads a single line at a time. `string.replace()` returns the entire string with the first argument replaced by the second. This means that the variables `postgres`, `dbname` and `dbrwuser` all contain a copy of the entire file with only the given strings replaced. I.e. `dbrwuser` still has `# DBENGINE=MYSQL` in it and `postgres` still has `'# DBRWUSER="user1"` in it.  Also, the `w` option in `f = open()` will overwrite the file every time.

Comment: @jDo wow, sounds like I messed. Should I fix like "with open(filename).... ? What is the best way?

Comment: I've turned the comments into an answer and added some more details. Feel free to ask if anything seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make three copies of the input instead of replacing it each time. Use the following:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBENGINE=MYSQL', 'DBENGINE=PGSQL')
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBNAME=DB1', 'DBNAME=DB1')
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBRWUSER="user1"', 'DBRWUSER="user1"')
...
f.write(filedata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by take all replacement string into a dictonary

```
import re
repString = {'# DBENGINE=MYSQL': 'DBENGINE=PGSQL', '# DBNAME=DB1': 'DBNAME=DB1', '# DBRWUSER="user1"': 'DBRWUSER="user1"'}

repString = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in repString.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(repString.keys()))
filedata = pattern.sub(lambda m: repString[repString.escape(m.group(0))], filedata)
f = open('/path/to/file', 'w')
f.write(filedata)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions and clarifications:

`f.read()` reads the entire file. This is probably not a good idea for large files. Instead, use

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with the line
```

Using `with open()` also eliminates the need for closing the file afterwards - it's done automatically.

`string.replace()` returns the entire string with the first argument replaced by the second. Since you make a new variable every time you use `replace`, the changes only apply to the individual variables. Changes made in `postgres` will not exist in `dbname`.
Instead, redefine the variable `filedata` for every `replace` to keep the changes and avoid needless copying:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBENGINE=MYSQL', 'DBENGINE=PGSQL')
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBNAME=DB1', 'DBNAME=DB1')
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBRWUSER="user1"', 'DBRWUSER="user1"')
# at this point, filedata contains all three changes
```

When you open a file for writing using the `w` option, the file is overwritten. This means that the file will only contain the contents written by your last write, `f.write(dbrwuser)`. Instead, make your changes and only write once or append to the file instead:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('# DBENGINE=MYSQL', 'DBENGINE=PGSQL')
...
...

with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(filedata)
```